# you will find nothing! I swear!

Tags: riddle

What is greater than God,

more evil than the devil,

the poor have it,

the rich need it,

and if you eat it, you'll die?

Comment: Just a tip - most of the riddles/puzzles that are put on this site are either riddles the poster came up with themselves, _or_ they are riddles that we found elsewhere that are **not** widely known - and we **try to make sure that all outside puzzles have a source attaches to them.** I hope to see some more content from you in the future!

Comment: OK. I haven't read the rules yet ...

Comment: Try https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour and https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a duplicate, but the answer is

> 

(if you didn't get the joke, it's)

> nothing

because

> nothing is greater then God (in a majority of people's minds, anyway), nothing is more evil than the devil (again, in a majority of people's minds), the poor have (basically) nothing, the rich need (basically) nothing, and if you eat nothing, you'll die.

Comment: yes, I've just noticed, but before I posted it I didn't find it. shall I delete it myself?

Comment: That first spoiler block made me (literally) laugh out loud :-)